# In JavaFX-8, can a controller be dynamically added to a node not created using FXML/FXMLLoader?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

This may be a case of newb-swimming-upstream, but...

In the FXML file, one of the attributes identifies the controller. I am assuming that the controller and identified methods are bound to the node during load (i.e., a controller instance is instantiated and its methods bound as listeners as identified in the FXML).

Is there a way to programmatically associate a controller instance with a JavaFX node (e.g., TableView) that was created procedurally vice via FXMLLoader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to define the controller instance in Java code, instead of letting the `FXMLLoader` instantiate it.

You can do this by calling `setController` on the `FXMLLoader` before you call `load()`. Note that this means you must create an `FXMLLoader` instance and invoke the *instance* `load()` method, and must not call the *static* `load(URL)` method:

```
MyController controller = new MyController();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

If you use this technique, you *must not* use the `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file.

Note that this gives you the ability to instantiate the controller any way you like - e.g. if you have controller classes which have constructors that take parameters you can use them here (controllers used by the default mechanism must have a zero-arg constructor).

**More advanced but related information:**

A related technique, but perhaps for more specialized use cases, is to set a controller factory on the `FXMLLoader`. The controller factory is a function that maps a `Class<?>` (the one defined by the `fx:controller` attribute) to an object (the controller). This essentially gives you programmatic control over the way the controllers are instantiated (typically using reflection). One use of this is if you have a model class:

```
public class Model { /* ... */ }
```

and several different controller classes that take a model reference as a constructor parameter. Typically you would want to use the same model instance and pass it to all controllers. So you could define a controller factory as follows:

```
Model model = new Model();
Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory = type -> {
    try {
        // look for a constructor with a single parameter of type Model:
        for (Constructor<?> c : type.getConstructors) {
            if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameterTypes()[0] == Model.class) {
                return c.newInstance(model);
            }
        }
        // no constructor found, just invoke no-arg constructor as in default:
        return type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
};
```

Then you can set the controller factory on your `FXMLLoader`(s):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Another use of this technique is in conjunction with dependency-injection frameworks such as Spring and Guice. If you configure a DI framework to instantiate controllers for you, and perhaps inject model instances into them, you can use the controller factory to allow the `FXMLLoader` to retrieve the controller instances from the framework. E.g. with Spring:

```
ApplicationContext context = ... ;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

or with Guice:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(...);

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: I was unclear. I am not using FXMLLoader (i.e., no FXML file), but simply hand-rolled the node. The "obvious answer" is "use FXML they way it's intended", but I was just curious to see if there is a way to do otherwise.

It may be a bit of a hack, but I have noted that I can simply instantiate a controller instance when generating the node, and then register event handlers onto the node before handing the node back to the caller.

Comment: Do what though? If you are creating the controls in code, I don't understand what you are wanting to do. Edit your question to include some code indicating what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

So, this appears to be (a) a result of my being new at GUI development, and (b) even newer at using JavaFX.

The bottom line appears to be...

If you are going to insist on using JavaFX components in a non-FX manner (i.e., no FXML files, no use of FXMLLoader), then be prepared to register event handlers in a non-FX style (add them procedurally during construction of the node).